# How to redirect urls for images with .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Old urls:

```
1. https://example.com/images/1/image1.png
2. https://example.com/images/2/image2.png
3. https://example.com/images/3/image9.jpg
4. https://example.com/images/4/image19.jpg
```

New urls:

```
1. https://example.com/images/101.png
2. https://example.com/images/202.png
3. https://example.com/images/309.jpg
4. https://example.com/images/419.jpg
```

Rules:

1. folder "**1**" + "**0**" + "**1.png**"
2. folder "**2**" + "**0**" + "**2.png**"
3. folder "**3**" + "**0**" + "**9.jpg**"
4. folder "**4**" + "**19.jpg**"

Now I have this code for .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Rewrite index.php to /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]

# Rewrite Query/ to Query
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^24$ / [R=301,L]

# Rewrite Query to index.php?route=Query
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?route=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: May you post any specimen of the code you already have?

Comment: Added the code for .htaccess to the post

Comment: Your "rules" don't seem to match your examples since you appear to be dropping "image" from the filename entirely in the preceding examples?

Comment: @MrWhite, thanks for the note, corrected. Now I will try to use your code and write about the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Immediately after the `RewriteEngine On` line try the following:

```
RewriteRule ^images/(\d+)/image(\d)\.(png|jpg)$ /images/$10$2.$3 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^images/(\d+)/image(\d{2,})\.(png|jpg)$ /images/$1$2.$3 [R=301,L]
```

The first rule handles the image names that contain a single digit (that must be prefixed with `0`) and the second rule handles the rest.

The `$1`, `$2` and `$3` backreferences match the corresponding capturing subgroups in the preceding `RewriteRule` *pattern*. In other words, `$1` contains the folder name (all digits), `$2` contains the number that appears after the filename and `$3` contains the file extension (either `jpg` or `png`).

NB: Test first with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues.

To clarify, presumably you are already linking to the new image URLs internally?

Comment: I checked it on the test site, everything works fine, thanks!